# attempting to reference a deleted function when passing by reference with a const member

Tags: c++

I'm clearly missing something out.

If I have:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    const int something;

    MyClass(int Something) : something(something) {}
};
```

This will fail (attempting to reference a deleted function) because I have no copy constructor

```
std::vector<MyClass> myStuff;
std::sort(myStuff.begin(), myStuff.end(), 
    [](MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs) { 
        return lhs.something > rhs.something; });
```

So I should pass by reference. But I have the same problem even if the lambda becomes

```
[](const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) { 
    return lhs.something > rhs.something; });
```

What's the reason behind this? The workaround is clear (don't have const member variables), but I want to know what I'm missing in the above example.

Comment: `sort` needs to move the items around inside the vector.  You can't do that since the class is not copy assignable or move assigneable.

Comment: @NathanOliver And the move constructor is missing from the same reason, right?

Comment: Yes the copy and move assignment operators are deleted since you have a `const` member.

Comment: Always **copy-paste** error messages. The compiler should be complaining about a deleted copy assignment operator, not a deleted copy constructor. `sort` requires the things you're sorting to be assignable, your class isn't.

Comment: @Praetorian Shouldn't the constructors be deleted when the operators are?

Comment: Why would they be? Constructors can *initialize* `const` members, but once initialized, they cannot be *(re)assigned*. So the assignment operators are deleted, while the constructors aren't.

Comment: @Praetorian this is panfully obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class has a const member, while you are asking std::sort to basically swap instances of your class around. Unlike a Java ArrayList, which contains handles (garbage-collected pointers) to the objects, C++ STL containers *directly* contain the objects themselves. Thus, you cannot swap the instances around because that would mean overwriting a const object. Your solution will have to be one of the following:

- Sort a vector of pointers or references to the objects: you can use `vector<MyClass*>` or `vector<reference_wrapper<MyClass>>` if you have the instances elsewhere, or `vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` if the vector *owns* the instances.
- Make the field non-const. Then your class will have a copy assignment operator (and a move ctor/op=, but with only that member it would be identical)
- Provide a custom move/copy op= that uses `const_cast` to cast away the const-ness of the field. This is a *bad* idea, since the standard says it is undefined behaviour (i.e. the compiler and program may set your computer aflame if they want to) under certain cases. I don't remember the exact standardese, but you would have to be *very* careful not to fall in one of the jolly C++ undefined behaviour traps.

Comment: I come from a C background, but I get the Java example. I can simply remove the const and make that a private and implement a getter for it, althrough I'd like to have a read only public member.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires that the elements the iterators point to are [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) and [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible).  You class is MoveConstructible but it is not MoveAssignable.  The reason for that is you have a `const` member.  You cannot assign to or move from a `const` member as that is a mutating operation.  You can provide you own copy or move assignment operator to get around this or just make the member non const.