# attempting to reference a deleted function when passing by reference with a const member to a class

Tags: c++

This is sort of an extension to the question [attempting to reference a deleted function when passing by reference with a const member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657060/attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-when-passing-by-reference-with-a-cons)

I read that and I do understand the explanations given about the MoveConstructible (or at least, I believe), but I cannot figure out why, given the following code:

```
struct vertex {
    const double x;
    const double y;
    const double z;
};

const std::vector<vertex> test_vertices()
{
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;

    vertices.emplace_back(vertex(-3.0, -3.0, 0.0));
    vertices.emplace_back(vertex(3.0, -3.0, 0.0));
    vertices.emplace_back(vertex(0.0, 0.0, 1.5));
}
```

this code works flawlessly:

```
std::vector<vertex> panel_vertices = test_vertices();
draw(panel_vertices);
```

but this other code does not and returns a "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xutility(1762,1): error C2280: 'p_geometry::vertex &p_geometry::vertex::operator =(const p_geometry::vertex &)': attempting to reference a deleted function" (ignore namespaces, they are ok in the code):

```
class PanelView {

    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
public:

    PanelView(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char* l = 0);
    void setVertices(const std::vector<vertex>& vertices): vertices(vertices) {};
    void draw() {
        other_draw(vertices);
    };
};
```

I have no sort operator here, but besides that, I'm missing something, because both snippets of code appear to do the same thing.

**UPDATE**

After your responses (thanks!!) I tried to clarify both my thoughts and my doubts. I tried several configurations, and I can get that the copy operator is deleted when there're const members  (a pretty dumb behavior imho, because when you create a copy you're not trying to modify anything from the original, but that's outside of the scope of this question).

I came down with the following four scenarios [1, 2, 2bis, 3]:

```
#include <iostream>

struct vertex {
    const double x;
    const double y;
    const double z;
};

const std::vector<vertex> test_vertices()
{
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back(vertex {-3.0, -3.0, 0.0});
    vertices.emplace_back(vertex{3.0, -3.0, 0.0});
    vertices.emplace_back(vertex{0.0, 0.0, 1.5});
    return vertices;
}

class PanelView {
    std::vector<vertex> mvertices;
    std::vector<vertex> *mvpointer;
public:

    //[1] PanelView(const std::vector<vertex>& vertices): mvertices(vertices) {};
    //[2] void setVertices(const std::vector<vertex>& v)  {mvertices = v;  };
    //[2 bis] void setVertices(std::vector<vertex> v)  {mvertices = v;  };
    //[3] void setVerticesPointer(std::vector<vertex> *v)  {mvpointer = v;  };
    void draw() {std::cout<<mvertices[0].x; };
    void drawp() {std::cout<<(*mvpointer)[0].x; };
};


int main()
{

    std::vector<vertex> panel_vertices = test_vertices();

    //[1] Works fine
    //PanelView pv(panel_vertices);
    //pv.draw();

    //[2 and 2 bis] - Error C2280: 'vertex &vertex::operator =(const vertex &)': deleted
    //PanelView pv;
    //pv.setVertices(panel_vertices);

    //[3] - OK
    PanelView pv;
    pv.setVerticesPointer(&panel_vertices);
    pv.drawp();


    std::cout<<panel_vertices[0].x;
}
```

The PanelView constructor [1] and the setVertices method [2 and 2 bis] do the same exact thing, take "const std::vector& vertices" as input and copy it (or what?) to the class attribute "std::vector mvertices;".

**First doubt**: why with the setVertices method it fails, while with the constructor it does not? What is the difference "behind the scene"?

**Second doubt**: I always believed that in C++ passing by reference and passing by pointer was basically the same, but passing by reference was more C++-style and avoided all the boilerplate code, making it more readable. Why the compiler complains with [2 (by reference)], but is ok with [3 with pointers]?

Comment: The working flawlessly code is interesting, because `test_vertices` is not returning anything.

Comment: Does it make sense to return a const std::vector<vertex> when you return a temp by value?

Comment: Also, void setVertices(std::vector<vertex>) has more sense than void setVertices(const std::vector<vertex>&). The caller can then decide wether to copy or move the argument into the member vertices.

Comment: vertex has no constructor vertex(double,double,double)

Comment: It does not make much sense to have all data members `const` as you could instead have none `const` and make the whole `struct` `const` wherever appropriate.

Comment: Actually, when you call a copy constructor, you actually ARE changing the object. vertex v1; vertex v2 = v1; does NOT call the constructor. It's an initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that in your example operator= - which is deleted - is not invoked and that is why it works. For contrast:

```
setVertices(const std::vector<vertex>& v)
```

takes an existing vector and *copy* each value, one by one, into a new vector `vertices`. Well at least this is the code compiler attempts to generate is something like:

```cpp
vertices.reserve(v.size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
 vertices[i] = v[i];
}
```

Note the above code expects an `operator=` to assign `vertices[i] = v[i];`
Also, note :) This is not the actual code that STL would generate - it is only for illustration point of where `operator=` is expected. Actual code is most likely to use generic copy algorithm and iterators.

As to your example - `vertices.emplace_back(vertex(0.0, 0.0, 1.5));` does not requere `operator=` as it calls copy constructor - which I believe is generated by default. Copy constructor is called via placement new.

Comment: why is the operator= deleted?

Comment: 'cause `vertex` has const members like `const double x;`. C++ compiler does not know how to generate `operator=` for your class if your class has a const memer . See the original question example.

Comment: I think the compiler knows how to create the copy constructor or assignment operator. But it should throw an error as shown in my answer (cannot assign const double). Are you sure the assignment operator cannot be created?

Comment: Ok, it seems clang implicitly deletes the copy constructor.

Comment: test_vertices() works because he doesn't return the vertices, and the compiler ignores the body of test_vertices(). If he returned vertices, it would not compile, because vertex::vertex(double,double,double) does not exist.

Comment: Sorry - the test_vertices() does work even if it return a value. It may indeed not compile as is, but return value is not the problem here: see https://godbolt.org/z/XrmdE_ for example.
The reason why it is ok to return vector even if members don't have operator= defined is because compiler will chose [copy elison](https://godbolt.org/z/XrmdE_) in this case.

Comment: If you do not define vertex::vertex(double,double,double), the code as is, +returning the vector, does not compile. If you don't return the vector, the compiler ignores the body of test_vertices as I said before. And therefore, the code, as is, compiles. In your example it works because you use aggregate initialization, as explained in my answer. And yes of course, there is no assignment here and no copy constructor involved. But, the code as is does not work.

Comment: code as is does not work - I assume as much. My point is that it indeed does not work, but not because of the absence of the return statement.

Comment: Ok. In this particular situation, I thought he DID manage to compile the code (with some compiler). The only reason I could think of was that that particular compiler ignored it because the function doesn't do anything (as it does not return anything, and only local variables are used).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's correct some errors in your code:

> vertices.emplace_back(vertex(-3.0, -3.0, 0.0));

You construct an instance of `vertex` with a user-defined constructor that does not exist: `vertex::vertex(double,double,double)`. You could solve that problem by implementing the constructor `vertex::vertex(double,double,double)`, or by using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
vertices.emplace_back(vertex {-3.0, -3.0, 0.0}); // C++11
vertices.emplace_back(vertex {3.0, -3.0, 0.0});
vertices.emplace_back(vertex {0.0, 0.0, 1.5});
```

Another line which is actually no valid C++ code:

> void setVertices(const std::vector& vertices): vertices(vertices) {};

My best guess is you meant something like:

```
void setVertices(std::vector<vertex> v) { vertices = v; }
```

Well, this code would not compile since you have `const` members in your `struct vertex`. In other words, it is impossible to change the value of any of the members of `vertex`, and hence, it is impossible to change any of the instances of `vertex` in your vector `vertices`. The compiler would tell you something like: `error: static assertion failed: type is not assignable`. This problem can be solved by removing the `const` keyword.

The error `attempting to reference a deleted function` is due to the above mentioned: the copy constructor (or copy assignment operator) is deleted because you cannot assign an instance of `vertex` to another instance of `vertex`.

```
gcc 10.0.0: error: static assertion failed: type is not assignable

clang 10.0.0: copy assignment operator of 'vertex' is implicitly deleted because field 'x' is of const-qualified type 'const double' const double x;
```

As a side note, the signature of `test_vertices` should read like this:

```
std::vector<vertex> test_vertices() // remove the const, as you return a local variable by value
```

And, more importantly, your `setVertices` function should read like this:

```
void setVertices(std::vector<vertex> v) { vertices = std::move(v); } // C++11
```

And hey, then **everything suddenly compiles**, with or without the `const` members of `vertex`. Why is that? Because you never try to copy an instance of `vertex`. The argument `std::vector<vertex> v` is initialized when `setVertices` is called, but no copy assignment or constructor is involved. The argument `std::vector<vertex> v` is simply initialized with another `vector`. Furthermore, the user can now decide whether to move that other vector or create a copy of it (without invoking the copy instructor :p):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<vertex> my_vertices = test_vertices();
    setVertices(my_vertices); // no copy constructor, v gets initialized with my_vertices. But, now there exists a copy of my_vertices (which is v)
    setVertices(std::move(my_vertices); // move my_vertices into v
    return 0;
}
```

Last but not least, I would like to reiterate a comment of @Phil1970:

> It does not make much sense to have all data members const as you
>   could instead have none const and make the whole struct const wherever
>   appropriate.

This means that, instead of adding the `const` type qualifier to your members of `vertex`, you could simply remove it and use an object of `const` vertices:

```
const vertex> my_vertex;
```

Then again, you cannot do:

```
std::vector<const vertex> my_vertices;
```

since items in a vector must be assignable.

Anyways, you probably don't need the members of `vertex` to be `const`.

**Answers to your updated question.**

> First doubt: why with the setVertices method it fails, while with the constructor it does not? What is the difference "behind the scene"?

```
PanelView(const std::vector<vertex>& vertices): mvertices{vertices} {}
```

This works because you are not calling the copy constructor. You just are initializing `mvertices`, and this is exactly the source of your confusion.

```
vertex v1 = {-3.0, -3.0, 0.0}; // this is not an assignment, it is an initialization
vertex v2; // declaration -> the members are initialized with default values
v2 = v1; // assignment -> the copy constructor is called: error
```

So, in the last line, you are trying to change the default values of `v2` by those of `v1`, which is not possible as your members are `const`. However:

```
vertex v3 = v2;
```

Here `v3` is initialized with `v2` and no copying occurs.

That said, the constructor should read:

```
PanelView(std::vector<vertex> v) : mvertices{std::move(v)} {}
```

Your `setVertices` does not work because you assign `v` to `mvertices`, hence you are calling the copy constructor, which is implicitly deleted. You should `move` `v` into `mvertices` as explained earlier.

> Second doubt: I always believed that in C++ passing by reference and passing by pointer was basically the same, but passing by reference was more C++-style and avoided all the boilerplate code, making it more readable. Why the compiler complains with [2 (by reference)], but is ok with [3 with pointers]?

A reference variable can be said as another name for an already existing variable. Pointers, on the other hand, are variables that store the address of a variable. And you can copy the pointer as many times you want. However, that doesn't mean you are copying the object itself. You should be careful with such practices, as several pointers would point to the same object, but I'll consider this out of scope. You should avoid raw pointers to vectors.

Comment: Thanks MFnx! I edited the question with your suggestions. About the use of const data members instead of const struct... in an ideal world, yeah, but we are working on an OpenGl project, vertices will be passed around by pointer for performance purposes, and nothing could stop them from doing:

vertex \*v2 = (vertex\*) &const_vertex1;
v2->x = "Something to screw up everything"; //If x, y, z are const, compiler would complain

Comment: @Duccio The compiler would not complain if you use the signature of setVertices as explained in the answer. In that case, your data members may be const.

Comment: @Duccio 2 bis does not work because you don't MOVE v into myvertices. Check again my implementation of setVertices. I recommend you read and understand the concepts of copy, move, and especially initialize vs assignment. int i = 1; is an initialization. int j; j = i; is a declaration followed by an assignment. +1 for your effort.